# node-gyp configure fails with binding.gyp not found error

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio

On running the node-gyp configure it throws the error as binding.gyp not found. But we dont have a binding.gyp file within our project folder. 
Node version is 6.9.2 and msvs is community edition 2015, Python 2.7. PFB the error

```
D:\Updated_Node\IMV\IMV>node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.5.0
gyp info using node@6.9.2 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'D:\\Updated_Node\\IMV\\IMV\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\
gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Updated_Node\\IMV\\IMV\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Updated_Node\\IMV\\IMV\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon
.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sanna_basheer\\.node-gyp\\6.9.2\\include\\node
\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\sanna_basheer\\.node-gyp\\6.9.
2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=D:\\Updated_Node\\IMV\\IMV\\node_modules\\
node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\Updated_Node\\IMV\\IMV',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Updated_Node\\IMV\\IMV\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: D:\Updated_Node\IMV\IMV) while trying to load b
inding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (D:\Updated_Node\IMV\IMV\node_module
s\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:308:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Updated_Node\\IMV\\I
MV\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Updated_Node\IMV\IMV
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```